# Remove "Custom fields" metabox in Woocommerce order edit pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the 'postcustom' meta box from the order details for a simple wooCommerce shop. The div #postcustom appears in Orders--->Click on single order --> bottom of page as 'Custom Fields'. I want to get rid of it. There are loads of examples of how to do this by calling the following function:

```
function remove_custom_field_meta_box()
{
    remove_meta_box('postcustom', 'page', 'normal');
}
```

I've hooked it (currently) into:

```
//Remove postcustom meta box
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_custom_field_meta_box');
```

I've also tried 'dashboard' and 'post' as $context to no avail.

I've also tried hooking to remove_meta_boxes, admin_init, and a few others.

I'm working in a child themes functions.php and using the default wooCommerce theme. Any thoughts on why this isn't firing? That pesky #postcustom div is still there in the admin menu! Is my context incorrect? I also tried 'orders'. Thanks@

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated:** For orders in Woocommerce the post type is **`'shop_order'`**, so your code should be:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'remove_shop_order_meta_boxe', 90 );
function remove_shop_order_meta_boxe() {
    remove_meta_box( 'postcustom', 'shop_order', 'normal' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). **Tested and works**.

---

Or you can **hide it** hitting the "screen options" tab and unchecking "Custom Fields" checkbox:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This did work. Question: where did you find the 'context' just from the woocom docs? Also I also want to remove the downloadable option as well (would prefer to do it with a function) And the following does not work (copy/paste from yours with new div name) function remove_download_field_meta_box()
{
    //remove_meta_box('postcustom', 'shop_order', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box('woocommerce-order-downloads', 'shop_order', 'normal');
    //remove_meta_box('woocommerce-order-label', 'shop_order', 'normal');
}

Comment: @HectorOfTroy407 [I have already used custom metaboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+add_meta_box) for order edit pages and the context is the post-type, so for Orders is the custom post_type "shop_order"